# Booked a trip on Kiwi: one of the flights was cancelled, alternatives don't fit me. What are my rights?

Tags: cancellations, passenger-rights, easyjet, kiwi

I booked a trip on Kiwi (4 flights):

Zurich > Oslo, Oslo > Tromso, Tromso > London, and London > Zurich

The last leg was cancelled. They suggest alternatives but there all very unpractical. Other (practical alternatives) are expensive.

What are my rights?

For those who are interested here is how Kiwi handled it:

I called them. They promised to come back to me within 48hrs and that I would not lose the "kiwi guarantee". I got a (blanket?) email ~1hr after ending my call with them. The content of the email was: 
(a) we found no alternatives for you
(b) I lose my guarantee

I called them back on the next day. Calling them out on the fact that they had promised i would retain my "kiwi guarantee" (I also recorded the call on my end). Based on that they agreed to forward me to the somebody who would have a closer look at my case.

I got a call ~1 hr after from a friendly assistant who offered an option (extremely unpractical: Tromso - Oslo - London - Porto - Zurich) requiring a night layover for which I would need to pay ~40USD + accomodation.

How I solved the problem:
I went to the easyjet website (the flight cancelled was an easyjet one), to "manage disruptions" changed the arrival airport from Zurich to Geneva. Cost 0$ and I fly out only one hour later

I now need to take the train from Geneva to Zurich - which is a very minor disruption in comparison with all the solution they offered.

Comment: Did you already call Kiwi customer service? Cause if not, I'd suggest you just try that first, might be less about your rights than about the goodwill of Kiwi.

Comment: How long in advance were you notified of the cancellation? Are all flights separate or are they connecting (either for real or “a la Kiwi”)? What kind of travel insurance do you have?

Comment: I called customer service: they said they would come back to me in the next 48hrs @MaxD

Comment: How long in advance were you notified of the cancellation? well in advance (a few weeks). All flights were purchased together as a package, but different airlines. What kind of travel insurance do you have? the one of my cc. @jcaron

Comment: @John What do you mean by ‘very unpractical’?

Comment: @Traveller I would arrive a day later and I need to organize accomodation in layover city

Comment: Already heard back from KIwi? I'm curious how they handle it.

Comment: @MaxD I updated the question

Comment: If you have answered your own question it is actually better to write it in an answer, not as part of the question.

Comment: @DJClayworth I don't think i answered my question: in my opinion kiwi is offering bad travel alternatives and glamorously label them under the "kiwi guarantee" to avoid the consequences (and their cost) of EU air passengers rights: https://europa.eu/youreurope/citizens/travel/passenger-rights/air/index_en.htm#cancellation. but it would be interesting know about more knowledgeable people

Comment: I'm not sure what kind of answer you are expecting. It's relatively obvious that Kiwi would owe you your money back if they promise a service and can't deliver it, both based on their guarantee and on common sense (If I give you money for something and you don't give it to me you give me my money back). But getting a full refund is the normal standard when an airline changes a flight, and it;s unlikely you can force Kiwi to do more than that.

Comment: at no point in time was I offered a refund - this is what i mean with "right", see my updated comment above.

Answer (score 2):

If you make a booking with an airline, and they then significantly change the flight details (typically changing departure or arrival by more than a few hours) then the normal minimum standard is that they must give you a full refund. This is based on established practice and basic legality - if I pay you money for something, and you can't deliver that something, then you have to give me the money back.

Airlines are reluctant to talk about this full refund, and will do a lot to persuade you to take another flight with them - after all, they want your money. But it is virtually incontrovertible that they have to give you a full refund. They are unfortunately not obliged to do more than that, even though finding an alternative flight might have become more expensive by the time the change/cancellation occurs.

In the case of Kiwi, [Kiwi do say very clearly that they will give you an alternative or a refund](https://www.kiwi.com/en/pages/guarantee). They don't say in the guarantee that it will be an acceptable flight, but I think a lawyer is going to have a field day if they only offer you a completely unacceptable alternative and refuse to give you a refund.